# modal form with form-horizontal style not aligned while inside loop

Tags: modal-dialog

Good day, I have this code that generate list of items

it goes like this:

```
for($i=0; $row = $qryAllItems->fetch(); $i++) {echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $itemName . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $itemDescription . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $currentQuantity . ' ' . $unitType . '</td>';
echo '<td>Php ' . $unitCost . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $itemSupplier . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $itemBrand . '</td>';
echo '<td><center><span class="label label-success">'. $itmStatus .'</span></center></td>'; echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" title="View Item Details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewItemDetails'. $itmIndex .'" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> </button> </td>';}
```

This is will allow me to view each item inside a modal. However, when the modal shows, its alignment is distorted: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBFVP.jpg)

Would anybody be willing to point out where i made a mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: The image looks fine, where exactly is it not aligned?

Comment: oh well, after an hour of looking at it with the help of google, it is now aligned. Thanks you guys. Resolve it by adding form-horizontal to modal-body instead of putting it at the form.